# separating a string into a substring dynamically VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, dynamic, substring

I am currently working on a grocery store ordering system for a school project and need some help dynamically separating a string into substrings.

I need to get the product name (Grapes) out of this example string.
"1                      Grapes             5.99"

Each one of those values is separated by a tab.

Sorry if this isn't enough information, this is my first post

Comment: there is probably a good way to avoid having to parse altogether.  where does the string come from?  (prediction: Listbox or ComboBox)

Comment: how about? sp = split("1 Grapes 5.99"," ").... then use sp(1) to get grapes

Comment: make sure that you specify something like vbtab or char(9) for the second parameter in the split command.

Comment: If you are asking a question like this, this may be a little challenging for you, but a powerful tool to parse apart string values to get useful data is by using Regular Expressions. Try taking a look at: https://www.google.com/search?q=using+regex+with+vb.net

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Comment: Kidding about that, but regex is probably a heavy-handed approach to solving a simple problem like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `String.Split` method:

```
Dim source As String = "1   Grapes  5.99"
Dim split As String() = source.Split(ControlChars.Tab)
Dim item As String = split(1)
Console.WriteLine(item)
```

That will work, assuming that the product name is always the 2nd tab-delimited item in your string.

`ControlChars.Tab` is in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace and is probably a better idea than using the legacy `vbTab` constant.  Same goes for using `String.Split` instead of the legacy vb `Split` function.  I generally consider it bad form to use those backwards-compatibility tidbits when there is a .Net equivalent you can use instead.

Comment: Thank you, this worked great. Also thank you for the advice for future projects!